# Problem to update list item with flutter redux?

Tags: redux, flutter, bloc

I am working with cart list and wants to update my cart after choosing. So i need to update list item. What shall be the process to do so?

I have tried with redux. The list data will be removed after app refresh/reopen. I can add and remove items. but I am facing problem while updating list item.

For adding I have done something like this -

```
List <Item> addItemReducer(List<Item> state, action) {
  return []
    ..addAll(state)
    ..add(Item(id: action.id, body: action.item, cost: action.price));
}
```

To remove the process I have used -

```
List <Item> removeItemReducer(List<Item> state, action) {
  return List.unmodifiable(List.from(state)..remove(action.item));
}
```

Keyword 'add' for insert and 'remove' for delete is available 'update' keyword is not available. If I try to type 'update' it shows error.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?